# Hide table rows one by one when click them using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have usual sql scenario with php (mysqli_fetch_assoc) and create table. I want to hide rows randomly when i click on them. I may also need to delete them from the database at the same time, because this file is calling from another with ajax every 5 sec. and hiding is not enough because after calling the rows  appear again.. :) I'm no sure that this is the best solution but I'm learning now.

I'm trying something like this it's working, but i can hide only last row. I want hide every row randomly :)

```
jQuery().ready(function(){
  $( "#trow" ).click(function() {
    $( "#trow" ).hide()
  });
});

<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_down)):    
    $datetime = $row['datetime'];
    $device = $row['host'];
    $message = $row['msg'];      
?>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="trow">
       <td id="device"><?php echo  $datetime;?></td>
       <td id="datatime"><?php echo $device;?></td>
     <  td id="message"><?php echo  $message;?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>      
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: `$( "#trow" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).hide()
  });`

Comment: in HTML, the ID of an element must be unique. You are creating lots of rows with the id "trow". jQuery cannot tell them apart - that's the main problem here.

Comment: OK, I create lots of rows with this id but why hide only the last row in the table ? My be because this is a "while php loop"? I don't now how can i do different "id" when new row is appear.

Comment: Use a class - further to adyson's comment, jquery will only get the first item with that id as it expects ids to be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the `trow` from an id to a class name

```
<tbody>
<tr class="trow">
   <td id="device"><?php echo  $datetime;?></td>
   <td id="datatime"><?php echo $device;?></td>
 <td id="message"><?php echo  $message;?></td>
</tr>
```

And in the JQuery side, call the click event on the class and not the id this time. The `$(this)` means the clicked element.

```
jQuery().ready(function(){
  $( ".trow" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).hide()
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply hiding rows after a click can be done like this:

```
(function () {
  $('table tr').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
})();
```